# Preserve DOM element highlighting in chrome dev tools / firebug

Tags: dom, firebug, selection, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to preserve the highlight showing the boxmodel properties (width, margin, padding, border) of a DOM element? I'm trying to inspect the behaviour of an element when the window is resized so it would be nice to permanently see the measurements.

Solutions for both Chrome Developer Tools and Firebug (Firefox) appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible for Chrome DevTools, but you can open the `Metrics` pane in the right-hand side of the `Elements` panel to monitor content area/padding/border/margin when the window is resized.

Comment: As a good citizen, you are always welcome to contribute to the DevTools! https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/devtools-frontend/src/

Comment: We are in 2023 now. Is this still impossible?

Comment: Sadly, none of the previous authors have expressed desire to implement the feature. Perhaps try filing a feature request at http://crbug.com/new ?

Comment: 2024 and still nothing - bummer!

Comment: @DATEx2 I understand your frustration but since nobody has likely filed a request at the link above, this feature seems to be low priority even for users and is obviously under the ChromeDevTools team's radar. That said, StackOverflow may be a suboptimal forum for filing feature requests - please try http://crbug.com/new instead.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't the exact answer you're looking for, but if you give the element a display of flex, and inspect the element, you can click the flex button, and it will highlight it in orange on the screen for you. Hopefully the actual feature is added soon! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible in Firefox using dev tools.

1. Open dev tools inspector (`ctrl` + `shift` + `i`)
2. Click on the element you want to keep highlighted
3. In the CSS rules tab on the right click on the small square next to `element` selector.

[image: Small square that keeps element/s highlighted]

Additionally you can also highlight all elements that are using same CSS selector:

[image: Highlighting all elements under same selector]